# How do you set a static IP address for hosts that connect to a raspberry pi based wifi hot spot?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip, raspberry-pi

I'm looking to set static IP addresses for any device that connects to the pi via the wifi hotspot I created using hostapd and dnsmasq.  How do you to this?  Right now, it seems the IP may change after 24 hours of being disconnected - what's the correct way to ensure that any time a device connects to the pi using wlan0, it keeps that IP indefinitely?

Comment: Google told me that https://www.linux.com/topic/networking/dns-and-dhcp-dnsmasq/ might have the answer.

Comment: Apparently your google skills are better than mine. What am I doing with my life?

This shows me how to keep the IP indefinitely, but what about after reset? Do the settings persist?

Comment: I am sorry for my passive-aggressiveness. This is what I did: https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=dnsmasq+static+ip&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-jp&client=safari. First hit. I hope it does help you.

Comment: You don't need to be sorry! Literally - I spent a few hours on this and kept searching things like "static IP with raspberry pi wifi hotspot" and became frustrated that all the links were about using the pi with a static ip on ethernet - nothing to do with clients.

Comment: Your mistake was thinking that RaspberryPi, Wifi or hostapd had anything to do with your problem. Only one component of your setup produces IP addresses, namely dnsmasq. I focused my search on that, successfully I guess.

Comment: Note that "dhcp reservation" is not the same as "static". See `--dhcp-host` in the man page if you are using dnsmasq as the DHCP server.